# How to detect whether a x64 or x86 VCRedist installed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, vcredist

From [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx), we can get whether a more recent VCRedist installed from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE[\Wow6432Node]\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\14.0\RuntimeMinimum\Version`, but how can we get whether it's a x64 or x86 VCRedist? Since we can install both x86 and x64 VCRedist in x64 OS.

Comment: Presumably, the entry in Wow6432Node is for x86, and the other one is for x64.

Comment: 32 bit is in the 32 bit view, 64 bit in the 64 bit view. Don't ever hard code Wow6432Node. Read from the appropriate view.

Comment: It works fine, thank you, Harry and David